# Why doesn't this simple javascript in nodeRED for Visual Flow Creator work?

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm new to javascript and nodeRED.  I'm working in Visual Flow Creator and trying to take 4 values:

```js
var msg = {
    payload: {
        Dryblend_Dose_Finished: true, // Sample values, could be dynamically set
        Filler_Dose_Finished: true,
        Weight_Sent_DryBlend: 100, // Sample values, could be dynamically set
        Weight_Sent_Filler: 50
    }
};
```

...and when the 2 BOOLean vars are both TRUE, add the 2 "Weight..." values together, storing the result in a new property that will be added to the msg.payload array.

My Code:

```js
// Bring in the payload

var array = msg.payload;

// Check to see if the BOOLs are both TRUE

if (array.Dryblend_Dose_Finished === "true" && array.Filler_Dose_Finished === "true")
{   
    //add the 2 weights together and store for incorporation into the outgoing msg.payload
    array.total = array.Weight_Sent_DryBlend + array.Weight_Sent_Filler;
}
else {
    array.didntWork = 1;
}

// put everything back into the payload

msg.payload = array;

return msg;
```

It seems to me like this should be "simple" and yet, no matter what I do, it seems like it simply doesn't even run.  In my debug node after the function block, I get the same values out that went in with no changes.  I added the "didntWork" var thinking I might sanity check my logic, but that doesn't show up either, so now I don't even know if the stupid function is even running (except that nodeRED/Visual Flow Creator says the function completed in 4.08ms.

Anyone have any ideas?  This should not be that difficult, and yet this refuses to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"true"` is a string and not equal to Boolean `true`. For Boolean values, there's no need to compare to anything, simply use `if (array.Dryblend_Dose_Finished && array.Filler_Dose_Finished)`

Comment: There's also a difference between `===`  ([strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)) and `==` ([equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)). `true === "true"` will always be evaluated to `false` because the types (`boolean` and `string`) don't match. `true == "true"` will always be evaluated to `true` because they're both coerced to `true`.

Comment: @DM I was trying to avoid such advice because `true == "false"` is also `true`

Comment: `"false"` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value because its length is non-zero. `true == [""]` is also `true` because `[""]` is non-empty.

Comment: Like Phil said, you really want `if (array.Dryblend_Dose_Finished && array.Filler_Dose_Finshed)`. If you must inlcude a comparison, do a strict equality comparison with `true`: `if (array.Dryblend_Dose_Finished === true && array.Filler_Dose_Finished === true)`.

Comment: I started out with 'if (array.Dryblend_Dose_Finished && array.Filler_Dose_Finished)... ' and then put the code back to this, but no help

Comment: I have tested your code just with the corrected boolean expression live in Node-RED and it worked fine for me. I will add more info to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been given in the comments: Your code is syntactically correct, but there is a problem with your boolean expression. The way you are doing it will never behave as you would expect because you are comparing different types (boolean with string).

The variables `Dryblend_Dose_Finished` and `Filler_Dose_Finished` are already booleans, so you don't have to compare them. The boolean expression is as simple as `(array.Dryblend_Dose_Finished && array.Filler_Dose_Finished)`.

Besides that, there are minor issues with your variable names. What you call an *array* is not really an array in the sense of Javascript. An array looks like this: `var pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit']` and you can access the items via their index like `pets[1]` (which results in 'cat'). Property `payload` of object `msg` is an object itself which consists of the boolean properties `Dryblend_Dose_Finished`  and `Filler_Dose_Finished` and the numeric properties `Weight_Sent_DryBlend` and `Weight_Sent_Filler`. So, naming the variable an array may be misleading. In Javascript it is also a widely adopted to use ***camelCase*** naming instead of using '_' as a separator. Your variables would then look like `weigthSentFiller` or `weightSentDryBlend`. But not sure if you can influence the format of the message.

In addition, it is good practise to begin names of boolean variables with the verbs ***is*** or ***has*** like in `isFillerDoseFinished` or `node.hasChildren`. Using these naming conventions makes your code better readable and understandable. You would see at the first glance that `isFillerDoseFinished` is a boolean and that you don't have to check for equality in a boolean expression.

I have tested your code live in Node-RED by using an ***inject*** node with the following JSON input as payload:

```
{
    "Dryblend_Dose_Finished": true,
    "Filler_Dose_Finished": true,
    "Weight_Sent_DryBlend": 100,
    "Weight_Sent_Filler": 50
}
```

This results in exactly the object that you used in your example (see screenshot debug output *before*). Then I added a ***function*** node with your code, corrected the boolean expression and deployed it. As you can see in the debug output *after*, the new property `total: 150` was added to the payload.

[image: Node-RED screenshot]

I hope that helps :)